# How can i add links on discord via my bot

Tags: python, hyperlink, bots, discord, discord.py

Whenever the user inputs #armory *Character name* I want the bot to respond with a link for the user to click. 
My code is:-

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def armory(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await bot.say("armory.warmane.com/search/{}".format(user.name))
```

So for an example input: #armory Darkmist

The output will be: armory.warmane.com/search/Darkmist

However this is not a clickable link and I hope that somehow I could implement that.

And secondly is there a better way to implement the code I have just written? If so any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `await bot.say("https://armory.warmane.com/search/{}".format(user.name))`?

Comment: Yes this was correct and it works thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `https://` or `http://` to the start of the link. Otherwise discord doesn't recognize it, making it unclickable.